# Префикс th, когда используется?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

не совсем понимаю когда нужно ставить префикс th, например если сделать так:`<form th:method="post" th:action="/main">` вместо `<form method="post" action="/main">` - изменений не будет, стоп, или будет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Что обозначает префикс th?**

`th` обозначает пространство имён Thymeleaf в документе, содержащее доступные для управления элементами атрибуты.

Оно объявляется в начале документа

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xml:lang="ru-ru" lang="ru-ru">
```

**Что такое пространство имен?**

> Пространство имён в XML (англ. XML namespace) — это стандарт,
>   описывающий именованную группу имён элементов и атрибутов, служащую
>   для обеспечения их уникальности в XML-документе.
>   *(с)Wikipedia*

Это значит что на http://www.thymeleaf.org имеется стандарт, который описывает, какие именно атрибуты и элементы могут входить в данное пространство имен и, возможно, какие они могут принимать значения. В последствии можно будет валидировать XML документ с помощью данного стандарта.

**Что такое Thymeleaf?**

`Thymeleaf` - это шаблонизатор, который Spring предлагает использовать по умолчанию.
(По факту Вы можете использовать и другие шаблонизаторы. Никто этого не запрещает.)

Данный инструмент, как уже стало понятно использует XML в качестве шаблона.
Он находит все элементы, имеющие атрибуты объявленные в данном пространстве имен(th), и обрабатывает их в соответствии со своими инструкциями.

**Например:**

- Если в элементе указан атрибут `th:text="${object.property}"`, то шаблонизатор вставляет в указанный элемент текстовый блок, соответствующий значению свойства указанного объекта.
- Если в документе указан атрибут `th:href="${post.link}"`, то шаблонизатор вставляет атрибут href со значением, взяты из свойства link объекта post.
- Аналогичным образом работают атрибуты `th:value`,`th:class` и другие...они просто заменяют атрибут c NS th, на аналогичный атрибут HTML, только с предварительным вычислением выражения, которое было указано внутри данного атрибута.
- Также имеются возможности выполнять условия (выводить эделемент при соответствии условию) с помощью атрибута `th:if`
- Выполнять итерацию с помощью атрибутов `th:each`,`th:for`
- Выполнять вставку и замену других шаблонов с помощью атрибутов `th:include`, `th:replace` и объявлять фрагменты для многоразового использования с помощью атрибута `th:fragment`
- и многое другое

Подробно о всех возможностях шаблонизатора можно узнать на страницах документации: 
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Чтобы подытожить все сказанное:

- Все атрибуты в пространстве имен th заранее определены
- Относительно каждого атрибута в пространстве имен th шаблонизатор имеет четкие инструкции по его обработке
- Все атрибуты в данном пространстве имен будут обработаны шаблонизатором
- Все оставшиеся атрибуты будут проигнорированы, что обозначает то, что не имеет смысла использовать конструкции `${someObject.someProperty}` вне атрибутов, объявленных в данном пространстве имен.

Другими словами:

- если вы хотите, чтобы выражение было обработано шаблонизатором - то вы используете пространство имен `th`.
- если это статические элементы, которые не требуют обработки - то вы не указываете данный префикс.