# Данные из атрибута thymleaf в JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf

в X-editable для Bootstrap'a задаю pk через полученный ID в теге thymleaf, но почему то это значение не задается, и post запрос не уходит на сервер
в чем может быть ошибка?

Кусок HTML с тегом thymeleaf:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" id="dock" class="dockNumber" th:outboundtruck="${el.id}" th:text="${el.dockNumber}"></a>
</td>
```

Jquery код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dockNumber').editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk :   $(this).closest("td").attr("outboundtruck"),
        url: '/unload',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Thymeleaf` нельзя просто так добавить приставку `th:` к любому кастомному атрибуту и надеяться на то, что он обработается шаблонизатором.

Все атрибуты вида `th:some_attribute_name` заранее определены и перечислены в документации `Thymeleaf`.

В данном вопросе я подробно описывал, когда стоит, а когда не стоит использовать `th:` 
[Префикс th, когда используется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098424/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-th-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F/1098455#1098455)

Однако, это не отвечает на Ваш вопрос.

В Вашем случае данный атрибут(`th:outboundtruck`) просто не обрабатывается `Thymeleaf`, поэтому Ваш вопрос сводится к тому, как можно прокинуть кастомный произвольный атрибут в HTML с помощью `Thymeleaf`

Это делается с помощью `th:attr` или с помощью `th:attrappend`

Следующим образом:

```
<a th:attr="outboundtruck=${el.id}"></a>
```

Со всеми атрибутами будет выглядеть так:

```
<a href="#" 
   id="dock" 
   class="dockNumber" 
   th:attr="outboundtruck=${el.id}" 
   th:text="${el.dockNumber}"></a>
```

**Документация Thymeleaf**

- [th:attr](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute)
- [th:attrappend](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending)